# ruby split initial file contents into array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a file that I am reading that follows the following format:

```
12345,500,500
23456,100,150
34567,99,109
```

What I'm trying to do is read up until the first comma of the file and then map them into an array.

```
test = File.read('results.txt').split(',')[0]
p test 
 => "12345"
```

would return me back the first value before the comma but I want to put all of them into an array

```
test = File.read('results.txt').split(',')[0].map(&:strip)
```

I have tried the following above and other similar permutations but  unfortunately it's not quite the right it seems.

my desired result is to have an array of the following

```
[12345,23456,34567]
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: Updated question with my desired result.

Comment: In the first instance you say you want a single string (`"12345"`). Later you say you want an array of three integers. Which is it? In any event, if you want an array containing the first part of every line, that obviously gives you the first part of the first line, so I don't understand why the question even mentions the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to do that. First create the file.

```
txt =<<_
12345,500,500
23456,100,150
34567,99,109")
_

FName = "tmp"
File.write(FName, txt)
  #=> 43
```

**#1**

```
File.foreach(FName).map { |line| line[0, line.index(',')] }
  #=> ["12345", "23456", "34567"]
```

**#2**

```
File.foreach(FName).map { |line| line.to_i.to_s }
  #=> ["12345", "23456", "34567"]
```

[IO#foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) reads the file line-by-line, as contrasted by [IO#readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines), which "gulps" the entire file into an array. `foreach` is therefore less demanding of memory than `readlines`. You can write either `IO.foreach...` or `File.foreach...` as `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File < IO #=> true`).

Answer (score 0):

```
File.readlines('results.txt').map { |line| line.split(',') }.map(&:first)
=> ["12345", "23456", "34567"]
```